# Bottom navigation is refreshed every time the tab is moved

Tags: android, refresh, bottomnavigationview

Bottom navigation is refreshed every time the tab is moved.
I want to get view I opened before.

Should I replace bottom navigation with tablayout?

Help me please...

Comment: This question can be answered. You just need to add some code to your question and show what you have done so far. Then we can answer it. Otherwise the question should be closed